# Get Data from non-input element in Flask

Tags: flask

This is my Bootstrap button which works as dropdown.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger dropdown-toggle categoryButton" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Category</button>
```

I am using, flask to get the value . As it so stands, I want to get the value of the button, as it changes dynamically as I select differenet options from drop down list.
The values I select on drop down is reflected on the button, and now I want to grab it on Flask. 
But I could not find any way to get value of the button from Flask. 
I tried giving name attribute to the button and did this on Flask

```
category  = request.form.get('category')
```

But it returns none.Any help regarding this issue? Or should I go for another approach? 
Any help ?

Comment: Add a name attribute to your button. `name=category`

Comment: hmm, i'm afraid it's not enough, it needs a `value` attribute too, and the `type="button"` blocks the form-data, it could work with `type="submit"` but the button behavior will definitely change